Swiper v11 SwiperSlide isDuplicate is not supported with loop mode enabled
I am using swiper@11.1.3 with react, and in the type definitions of SwiperSlide wrapper component it seems like the interface does not support this:
interface SlideData { isActive: boolean; isVisible: boolean; isPrev: boolean; isNext: boolean; }
But it is not stated in the docs
https://swiperjs.com/react#swiperslide-render-function
This is a bad example, but:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/swiper-is-duplicate-s4d5tp?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A16%2C20
logging isDuplicate - end up in being undefined.
I didnt see this in the changelogs and documentation still says that it should work with loop mode enabled
I didnt see this in the changelogs and documentation still says that it should work with loop mode enabled
